# What is difference between these three sentences- "would", "would have", and "will"

Tags: modal-verbs, future-time, will-would

1.Tag those who'll attend her concert

2.Tag those who'd attend her concert

3.Tag those who'd have attended her concert

Answer (score 1):

1. Will means that, unless something drastic happens, they *will* definitely be there.
2. Would means that, if it's possible, they'll be there. Unless a better option arises...
3. Would have means that, they wanted to be there, but something prevented them, which, if it hadn't occurred, meant they'd be there.

Comment: 'would have' can be used for a guess... tag those who you think would have attended her concert. No?

Comment: @user236989 - I'd say could, or might for that.

Comment: No I think @user55625 means "Make a guess at how many would have been there". It could mean "would have been there unless something had prevented them", but it can also mean "How many do you think, in the circumstances, at that type of event, would you expect to have been there?". Only context will reveal which of the two senses of "would" is intended.

Answer (score 1):

In English there is a significant difference between the uses of would and will. Knowing when to use the terms correctly is an important part of mastering the English language.

Will and would are both types of auxiliary verbs that are known as modal verbs. Other modal verbs include: could, shall, might, may, can, ought to and must. Modal verbs don’t really have any meaning on their own, but act as helpers to give further meaning to other verbs.

Will is a definite statement, which means that you use it when you are certain that the future action is going to take place.

For example:

> [•] *I will go and collect the mail in the morning*

When you use will you or the subject executing the future action is committed to it being carried out.

The modal verb will can be used to talk about quick decisions, promises, offers and a likely prediction.

For example:

> [•] *I think I will take the bus instead of walking.*

instant decision;

> [•] *I’ll get the dog washed tomorrow.*

promise

> [•] *I will help you with your homework after dinner.*
>    offers and ‘I’ll bet she spent a lot of money on that dress.’ likely predictions.

Will is also used as a first conditional, which is used for cause and effect in situations that are not changeable.

For example:

> [•] *If it rains, you will get wet,’ or ‘If you are late to work, you will get in trouble.*

Would is an English modal verb and has many different uses, which include: invitations, requests, asking permission, talking about preferences and making arrangements.

For example:

> [•] *Would you like to come to the party on Saturday? is an invitation*
>   [•] *Would you be able to post this parcel for me?is a request*
>
> [•] *Would I be able to leave early today?’ is asking permission*
>   [•] *Would you like steak or chicken for dinner?’ or ‘I would prefer to eat ice cream’ are both examples of talking about preferences and ‘Would Friday at 8pm suit you?’ or ‘Saturday at 6pm would suit me.’ are ways to make arrangements using would.*

Would is also used in second and third conditional statements, which are used to talk about imaginary or unlikely situations.

For example:

> [•] *If I knew where he lived, I would visit him*

Is a second conditional statement. An example of a third conditional statement is thus: ‘If I had known about the party earlier, I would have gone.’ This is used to express an imaginary situation that took place in the past.

1.Would and will are both auxiliary modal verbs.
2.Will is used to talk about definite future actions.
3.Will is used to talk about: quick decisions, promises, offers and a likely prediction
4.Would is used to talk about: invitations, requests, asking permission, talking about preferences and making arrangements.
Both will and would can be used in conditional statements.

Would have is a bit more difficult because it has two common structures. The first is with but. I would have A, but I had to B. Use this structure to show that you wanted to do something in the past, but you could not.

> [•] *I would have called, but there was no phone service.*
>
> [•] *I would have loaned you the money, but I didn’t have any.*

Would have also forms the result clause of a past unreal conditional

For example:

> [•] *If I had known they were vegetarians, I would have made a salad.*

You can always reverse conditional sentences. If would have comes first, there is no comma.

> [•] *I would have made a salad if I had known they were vegetarians.*

Past unreal conditionals are very complex; you can learn more about them on a previous episode of Everyday Grammar.

Usually, would have suggests a bad feeling about the past. But not always. In this song by the band Chicago, the singer is surprisingly happy that his ex-girlfriend cheated on him. Her infidelity gave him the opportunity to meet someone else. And that someone else turned out to be his true love.

> [•] *If she would have been faithful.*
>
> [•] *Then I wouldn’ta been cheated.*
>
> [•] *I would never know real love.*
>
> [•] *I would've missed out on you*.

Sources:

http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-would-and-will/

https://www.google.dz/amp/s/learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/3391128.html

Comment: This is a very good answer and +1 for that. But I don't think you have included the sense of "would" referred to by @user55625 in their comment.